# What is the absolute superlative of "delicioso?"

Tags: adjetivos

I'm thinking it is "deliciosísimo/a," but when I check it on online translators, it comes up as nothing. I would just like confirmation that this is wrong (or right), and what the correct absolute superlative of "delicioso" is. Thank you.

Comment: just use riquísimo or extremadamente delicioso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To briefly answer your predicament:** it would not be grammatically wrong since you can say *muy delicioso* o *deliciosísimo*, but 'delicioso' is already expressing the maximum degree of the property to which it refers, without the need to add prefixes or suffixes. As such, it is in itself already an elative, a superlative of something that is very good and tasty. If something is already a superlative then technically that is where it stops. In other words, if 'delicioso' equals ‘muy sabroso’ or 'muy rico', the combination 'muy delicioso' or 'deliciosísimo' is redundant and 'poco delicioso’ would be contradictory. However, among morphologically anomalous adjectives, you will find the form ***deliciosísimo*** as absolute superlative in casual conversation/writing, usually in an humoristic or ironic tone, exagerations or emphatic answers (below is explained in detail by RAE).

It is possible also to detect such use in old books such as:

> In '[De Madrid a Nápoles](https://archive.org/stream/demadridnapoles00alar#page/336/mode/2up)' *de Pedro Antonio de Alarcón* (Madrid, 1878), pág. 337, it reads *"Las diez leguas que separan á Ferrara de Bolonia son **deliciosísimas.**"*
>
> In "[La Semana de Las Señoritas](http://cdigital.dgb.uanl.mx/la/1080073447/1080073447_MA.PDF#page=78)" (Méjico, 1851) pág. 150. 'Una Tertulia en Casa de Rossini' de *Stephen de La Madeleine*, it reads: "*Rossini... Rossini que á sus anchuras se recrea en su **deliciosísimo** far niento entre las flores de su querida villa.*"

## **Los superlativos absolutos y los adverbios de grado**

*[Fuente: RAE – NGLE 2009, § 13.3 y NGLE-Manual 2010, § 13.2.3]*

***Los adjetivos elativos léxicos rechazan el sufijo –ísimo.*** No obstante, al lado de adjetivos anómalos morfológicamente como *extraordinarísimo*, *descomunalísimo*, *enormísimo* o *insignificantísimo*, se registran formas como *excelentísimo*, ***deliciosísimo***, *preciosísimo*, *tremendísimo* o *perversísimo*, entre otros similares. Cuando se usan en la lengua coloquial, se percibe a veces en estas expresiones cierto sentido irónico o humorístico que no siempre se detecta en los textos antiguos o modernos:

*Ha educado su corazón y su mente con arte maravillosísimo igual al de los santos.*

Los superlativos absolutos formados con los sufijos - ísimo / -ísima, -érrimo / -érrima y os prefijos de grado extremo (re-, requete-, super-, hiper-, mega- o ultra-) se comportan también como adjetivos de grado extremo y tienden a rechazar los adverbios de grado porque esa combinación daría lugar a expresiones redundantes o contradictorias. Así excelente equivale, aproximadamente, a ‘muy bueno’, mientras que *muy excelente* es redundante y *poco excelente*, contradictorio.

Son frecuentes en el habla coloquial, aunque no son exclusivos de ella, los adjetivos o participios en uso adjetivo, que sin ser elativos, no suelen ser tampoco graduables. Se refieren a propiedades o estados que los hablantes suelen conceptuar como absolutos: solterísimo, casadísimo, muertísimo, rechazadísimo. La búsqueda del efecto cómico o irónico en los derivados en –ísimo a partir de bases léxicas que no admiten gradación es un rasgo característico de la lengua literaria:

El director, casadísimo; sus dos asistentes igual.

Estaba muerto, bien muerto, muertísimo.

También se usan los adjetivos en –ísimo en las respuestas enfáticas:
–¿Es secreto? –Secretísimo.

Asimismo, los derivados en –ísimo a partir de adjetivos ordinales (no graduables): primerísimo, ultísimo, y los formados a partir de bases nominales: campeonísimo, generalísimo o hermanísimo, cuñadísimo.
Los sufijos afectivos puede expresar cuantificación de grado. El adjetivo pequeñito posee sentido afectivo, como otros muchos diminutivos, lo que no impide que signifique ‘muy pequeño’.
Los adjetivos comparativos no admiten adverbios de grado, pero sí aceptan diminutivos restringidos:
con lo mejorcito,
ya estás mayorcito.

Comment: "Delicious" is not a superlative. Superlative is a grammatical form, not just a description of the intensity of meaning of a word.

Comment: @Aprendedor I can't cite anything, but I learned back in school (in Spanish) that some superlatives have special form, as "supreme", "maximum". It has to do with language evolution. I guess there'll be some different views, eg. structuralism vs. functionalism, etc. "Maximum" is just another way to say "the biggest", only taken straight from Latin.